# How can we schedule a Jenkins Job using Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins

If i need to schedule a jenkins Job using Python script at a particular instance of time.

Comment: You can use cornjobs/task schedulers to trigger python requests to Jenkins API. Your questions lack information however. Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I need my job at a single instance of time . I dont want to set any trigger. 
I was planning to use schedule build option in jenkins using python script